# IOS Variable vs Property

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Just started diving into Objective-C and IOS development and was wondering when and the correct location I should be declaring variables/properties. The main piece of code i need explaining is below:

Why and when should i be declaring variables inside the interface statement and why do they have the same variable with _ and then the same one as a property. And then in the implementation they do @synthesize tableView = _tableView (I understand what synthesize does)

Thanks :-)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> 
{
    UITableView *_tableView;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *_activityIndicatorView;
    NSArray *_movies;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *movies;
```

Comment: Also when is it appropriate to put ivars in the implementation file here 

`@implementation ChecklistsViewController {
    ChecklistItem *row0item;
    ChecklistItem *row1item;
    ChecklistItem *row2item;
    ChecklistItem *row3item;
    ChecklistItem *row4item;
}`

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there is no need to declare the instance variables for properties as the statement

```
@synthesize var = _iVar;
```

is actually generating an implicit variable named _iVar for you.

You would create properties when you want them to be accessible outside the class like

```
YourClass *obj = [[YourClass alloc] init];
obj.yourProperty = somevalue;
```

Properties also relieve you of writing your own getters & setters and take care of much of memory management themselves. Here is something you might wanna read plus other articles linked within the post.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/in-defense-of-objective-c-20-properties.html

Answer (score 2):

> Why and when should i be declaring variables inside the interface
>   statement

The instance variables are optionally defined inside the interface statement. You can alternatively define them in the implementation (or, for synthesised properties, not at all).

> why do they have the same variable with _

Having an underscore is just a convention for "private" variables. [The convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python) is followed in other languages as well. These are not mandatory.

> and then the same one as a property. And then in the implementation
>   they do @synthesize tableView = _tableView (I understand what
>   synthesize does)

Properties are a means of providing external objects access to variables of this class. If you intend to use a variable inside the class and do not mean/need to expose it to outside classes, then you do not need to define a property for it.

If your variable name and property name were the same you only have to write **@synthesize variableName**. However, if they are different e.g., when _ is added to the name by convention, then the statement **@synthesize variableName = _variableName** is telling that the property variableName sets and get the variable _variableName.